# Why the clone() is too slow if the elements are inside a <form>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, clone

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zKBwa/6/) you can find the whole example. 
By clicking on *Click to Add* you will clone 100 times the element `trackOn`; then it will be append to the table `tracklistOn`.

Unfortunatly, if these elements are inside a `form` you can see that the time is very high before the process is finish. **If I remove the form, is quite immediate. Why this behaviour?**

The whole code is here :

#### HTML

```
<div style="cursor:pointer;" id="addTr">Click to Add</div>   

<form action="index.php?status=add" method="POST">
    <table class="tracklistOn" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>

    <table class="tracklistOff" style="display:none;">
        <tr class="trackOn"> 
            <td class="trackTime">
                <select class="trackTimeHH" name="hours[]">
                    <option>??</option><option value="">-</option><option value="00">00</option>  <option value="01">01</option>  <option value="02">02</option>  <option value="03">03</option>  <option value="04">04</option>  <option value="05">05</option>  <option value="06">06</option>  <option value="07">07</option>  <option value="08">08</option>  <option value="09">09</option>  <option value="10">10</option>  <option value="11">11</option>  <option value="12">12</option>  <option value="13">13</option>  <option value="14">14</option>  <option value="15">15</option>  <option value="16">16</option>  <option value="17">17</option>  <option value="18">18</option>  <option value="19">19</option>  <option value="20">20</option>  <option value="21">21</option>  <option value="22">22</option>  <option value="23">23</option>  <option value="24">24</option>  <option value="25">25</option>  <option value="26">26</option>  <option value="27">27</option>  <option value="28">28</option>  <option value="29">29</option>  <option value="30">30</option>  <option value="31">31</option>  <option value="32">32</option>  <option value="33">33</option>  <option value="34">34</option>  <option value="35">35</option>  <option value="36">36</option>  <option value="37">37</option>  <option value="38">38</option>  <option value="39">39</option>  <option value="40">40</option>  <option value="41">41</option>  <option value="42">42</option>  <option value="43">43</option>  <option value="44">44</option>  <option value="45">45</option>  <option value="46">46</option>  <option value="47">47</option>  <option value="48">48</option>  <option value="49">49</option>  <option value="50">50</option>  <option value="51">51</option>  <option value="52">52</option>  <option value="53">53</option>  <option value="54">54</option>  <option value="55">55</option>  <option value="56">56</option>  <option value="57">57</option>  <option value="58">58</option>  <option value="59">59</option> 
                </select>
            </td>            

            <td class="trackTime">    
                <select class="trackTimeMM" name="minuts[]">
                    <option>??</option><option value="">-</option><option value="00">00</option>  <option value="01">01</option>  <option value="02">02</option>  <option value="03">03</option>  <option value="04">04</option>  <option value="05">05</option>  <option value="06">06</option>  <option value="07">07</option>  <option value="08">08</option>  <option value="09">09</option>  <option value="10">10</option>  <option value="11">11</option>  <option value="12">12</option>  <option value="13">13</option>  <option value="14">14</option>  <option value="15">15</option>  <option value="16">16</option>  <option value="17">17</option>  <option value="18">18</option>  <option value="19">19</option>  <option value="20">20</option>  <option value="21">21</option>  <option value="22">22</option>  <option value="23">23</option>  <option value="24">24</option>  <option value="25">25</option>  <option value="26">26</option>  <option value="27">27</option>  <option value="28">28</option>  <option value="29">29</option>  <option value="30">30</option>  <option value="31">31</option>  <option value="32">32</option>  <option value="33">33</option>  <option value="34">34</option>  <option value="35">35</option>  <option value="36">36</option>  <option value="37">37</option>  <option value="38">38</option>  <option value="39">39</option>  <option value="40">40</option>  <option value="41">41</option>  <option value="42">42</option>  <option value="43">43</option>  <option value="44">44</option>  <option value="45">45</option>  <option value="46">46</option>  <option value="47">47</option>  <option value="48">48</option>  <option value="49">49</option>  <option value="50">50</option>  <option value="51">51</option>  <option value="52">52</option>  <option value="53">53</option>  <option value="54">54</option>  <option value="55">55</option>  <option value="56">56</option>  <option value="57">57</option>  <option value="58">58</option>  <option value="59">59</option>             
                </select>    
            </td>            

            <td class="trackTime">
                <select class="trackTimeSS" name="seconds[]">
                    <option>??</option><option value="">-</option><option value="00">00</option>  <option value="01">01</option>  <option value="02">02</option>  <option value="03">03</option>  <option value="04">04</option>  <option value="05">05</option>  <option value="06">06</option>  <option value="07">07</option>  <option value="08">08</option>  <option value="09">09</option>  <option value="10">10</option>  <option value="11">11</option>  <option value="12">12</option>  <option value="13">13</option>  <option value="14">14</option>  <option value="15">15</option>  <option value="16">16</option>  <option value="17">17</option>  <option value="18">18</option>  <option value="19">19</option>  <option value="20">20</option>  <option value="21">21</option>  <option value="22">22</option>  <option value="23">23</option>  <option value="24">24</option>  <option value="25">25</option>  <option value="26">26</option>  <option value="27">27</option>  <option value="28">28</option>  <option value="29">29</option>  <option value="30">30</option>  <option value="31">31</option>  <option value="32">32</option>  <option value="33">33</option>  <option value="34">34</option>  <option value="35">35</option>  <option value="36">36</option>  <option value="37">37</option>  <option value="38">38</option>  <option value="39">39</option>  <option value="40">40</option>  <option value="41">41</option>  <option value="42">42</option>  <option value="43">43</option>  <option value="44">44</option>  <option value="45">45</option>  <option value="46">46</option>  <option value="47">47</option>  <option value="48">48</option>  <option value="49">49</option>  <option value="50">50</option>  <option value="51">51</option>  <option value="52">52</option>  <option value="53">53</option>  <option value="54">54</option>  <option value="55">55</option>  <option value="56">56</option>  <option value="57">57</option>  <option value="58">58</option>  <option value="59">59</option>
                </select>
            </td>            
        </tr>
    </table>        
</form>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('#addTr').click(function () {
    var savedTrackOn=$('.tracklistOff').find('.trackOn');
    for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
        savedTrackOn.clone().appendTo($('.tracklistOn'));
    }
});
```

How can I fix this problem?

#### EDIT

Tried it on Firefox 6.0, and the problems is vanished :O Only old version and chrome+IE? Why?

Comment: This is a great question.  I found that the performance varies per browser, but the pattern remains the same.  On a side note, I think an interface which wants me to select 100 times by using 3 different separate drop downs for each is something I would give up on very quickly.  There might be another way to do this altogether.  But I'd still like to know what causes this.

Comment: Yeah. In fact the code to "replicate" is not so huge... but the performance is really slow. Hope that someone can help us :)

Comment: Very interesting. I tried a few different things (i.e. using plain JS/DOM instead of jQuery; not having name attributes on the dropdowns; placing the template outside the form; using divs instead of tables; "cloning" with innerHTML instead of `.clone()` or `cloneNode()`; building the new rows "manually" with `createElement()`; etc.) but nothing really helped. As long as it's inside a form element, it's slow. Again: Interesting

Answer (score 4):

[The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone) clearly states the following:

> The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched
>   elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all
>   of their descendant elements and text nodes. When used in conjunction
>   with one of the insertion methods, .clone() is a convenient way to
>   duplicate elements on a page

Knowing this, it would be wise to limit the amount of deep traversal expected of `.clone()`.

This issue is completely unrelated to jQuery, as illustrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/Bh2eN/) where I've swapped out your code with host API code and the perceived performance issue still exists.

Lastly, I was able to identify another "work around" to this issue that would lead us to believe that the issue also lies in appending the new nodes, [take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/NfK9r/) and you'll see that moving the destination element *out* of the form also improves the performance drastically.

Comment: I think you could easily remove the form element and create the behaviour with JavaScript. A small amount of refactoring could easily solve your performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to flesh out my comment from earlier, and echo what Rick said.

I've tried the following (in Safari):

- Using plain javascript (no jQuery): **Still slow**
- Using divs instead of tables: **Still slow**
- Using `innerHTML` instead of `.clone()`/`cloneNode()`: **Still slow**
- Moving the template out of the form: **Still slow**
- Building the elements from scratch instead of cloning: **Still slow**
- Appending everything to a temporary element outside the form, and moving it afterwards: **Still slow**
- Hiding the form while appending elements: **Still slow**
- Removing name attributes on the input elements before cloning/copying/whatever: **Still slow**
- Removing the attributes on the form itself: **Still slow**
- Using plain numbering instead of list-style naming (i.e. "nameX" instead of "name[]"): **Still slow**

So, again, as long as you're appending those `select` inputs to a form element, it'll be slow.

But as Rick suggested, you can append the inputs to an element outside the form, and use JS to serialize and submit them.

Alternatively, you can append `input type="hidden"` elements to the form (which is fast) to the form, while appending the actual `select` elements to something outside the form. Then you could conceivably use event listeners to make the hidden inputs mirror the values of the selects. The hidden inputs will be submitted with the form, while the selects just function as a user interface.

Another option would be to have the dropdowns in the markup to begin with (which I suspect the browser would render fast), but having them be disabled and hidden. Then use javascript to unhide and enable the dropdowns when needed. I don't know if this will cause a slowdown too, but since new elements aren't being appended, it should be faster.

Still doesn't explain the slowness (or why it's apparently fast in FF6)

Comment: "Then you could conceivably use event listeners to make the hidden inputs mirror the values of the selects" : oh...this is a nice strategy! Didn't think about it to be honest :) Yeah, that slowness is very strange...nobody give to me a explanation...

Comment: Unfortunatly, I have many others input on the form, and I edit it dinamically. I think the only way is to serialize the item before send it to the server... (with jquery this will be easy and faster...)